# Differentiate between configuration change and real dismiss, in onDimiss callback of DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have the following `onDismiss` callback in `DialogFragment`.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // How to check whether this callback is caused by configuration change,
        // Or real dismiss?

        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}
```

`onDismiss` will be called in the following situation.

1. Press back button to quit the `DialogFragment`.
2. Touch outside dialog area to quit.
3. Call `dismiss()` explicitly.
4. Rotate the device.

I would like to differentiate between "real dismiss" (case 1 & 2 & 3) with configuration change (case 4)

In `Activity`, I usually do this to differentiate.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (this.isFinishing()) {
        // Real "termination"
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the similar thing in `DialogFragment`

Comment: How about handling configuration changes in you parent activity and adding a callback to your dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` class provides the [`isChangingConfigurations()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#isChangingConfigurations()) call, which allows you to check whether the activity is currently undergoing a configuration change. If you could access the activity during your `onDismiss()` callback, you could use that.

However, the dialog is dismissed *after* being detached from the activity, so `getActivity()` will return null inside this callback. Still, you can store a reference to that activity by implementing the `onAttach()` callback.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private MyActivity activity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.activity = (MyActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);

        if (activity.isChangingConfigurations()) {
            // your code here
        }
    }
}
```